# SSSD LDAP authentication using two different LDAP servers

Tags: pam, openldap, sssd

I am trying to setup LDAP authentication using SSSD on CentOS 7.

Is it possible to set up SSSD in a way that it uses two LDAP servers: one LDAP server is used just for login (basically just to authenticate with the password) and other LDAP server is used for getting all the other attributes of a user (homeDirectory, additional LDAP attributes defined only on that LDAP server)?

Users are defined on both servers (same uid, but different base).

Answer (score 1):

This (same) questions was answered at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/889011/448950):

> No, I don't think this is possible except with an ugly hack. The only
>   special-case that sssd supports is a different LDAP server for change
>   password operations (with `ldap_chpass_uri`).
>
> But what you could do is to use `id_provider=proxy`, configure it to
>   use `nslcd` (aka `nss-pam-ldapd`) and configure `nslcd` to use the identity
>   LDAP server. Then configure `auth_provider=ldap` and point it to the
>   auth LDAP server.
>
> It's not pretty and you would have two LDAP daemons running, but I
>   can't think of another way of solving the problem.